# How to execute function after click on layer control on leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I 'm using this command  `L.control.layers` to add radio button and checkbox on the map like this :

```js
var WMS_layers = {
    "<span id='factory' class='couches'>Parcelles</span>":factory_l,
    "<span id='bc' class='couches'>Bassin</span>": bc_l,
    "<span id='city' class='couches'>Commune</span>":city_l,
    "<span id='delivery' class='couches'>Parcelles</span>":cdr_l,
};
var WMS_parcelle = {
    "<span id='plot' class='couches'>Parcelles</span>":rdt_l,
};
// xxx_l is wms layer
L.control.layers(WMS_layers, WMS_parcelle, {collapsed: false}).addTo(mymap);
```

With this method I have `WMS_layers` with radio button and `WMS_parcelle` with a checkbox in the control layers.

To detect the click on the control layers I'm use this :

```js
$(".leaflet-control-layers-selector").on('click',function () {
    // get the selected option in the control layers :
    mymap.eachLayer(function () {
        if (typeof layer.options.layers !== "undefined") {
            var seleted_opt = layer.options.layers;
        }
    });
    //function calls
});
```

But with this method if the checkbox is selected I can't get the value of the radio button selected.

Comment: You could try `if (mymap.hasLayer(factory_1))` or similar.

Comment: @SebCollard: nice having found a solution by yourself, and sharing it! ;-) You should move it as an answer and accept it, so that people know your issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can found here the solution :

```js
$(".leaflet-control-layers-selector").on('click',function () {
    // get the selected option in the control layers :
    mymap.eachLayer(function () {
        if (typeof layer.options.layers !== "undefined" && layer.options.layers !== layer_name) {
            var seleted_opt = layer.options.layers;
        }
    });
    //function calls
});

//layer_name is the the name of my WMS_parcelle layer.
```

I just check if the selected layer is different to the checkbox layer and with this I can corretly execute the rest of the code, and I have only the value of radio button.